# Node.js reports URL as 200 instead of 404

Tags: node.js

I have an node.js app useing express.js running at http://bartonlp.org:8080.  I see this, for example, in my log output:

```
"GET http://www.baidu.com/?rnd=19712180733831423955225532 HTTP/1.0" 200 2749
```

I would have expected all other request to produce a 404 error, not a 200. This looks like the request for www.baidu.com actually got answered.

How can that happen? The only thing that I have in my app.get('/'... is for a main page.

Here is a very minimal node.js plus express.js app.js and route/index.js.
This gives the same results as the original files; here is a copy from my log file:

```
::ffff:94.102.49.174 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:22:29 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 975 "-" "Mozilla"
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:10 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/?rnd=3342104796019809757566816 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:10 +0000] "GET http://50.117.47.67:43530/?rnd=2031422537804277052916912 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:11 +0000] "GET http://123.249.29.201:43210/?rnd=173003480482578803940608 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:31 +0000] "GET http://123.249.29.201:43210/?rands=_518421966013600083518500 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:31 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/?rands=_14790662340951392923112 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:32 +0000] "GET http://50.117.47.15:28712/?rands=_71269649426275522095128 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:33 +0000] "GET http://50.117.86.106/?rands=_146883056102225940108720 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:62.210.162.182 - - [23/Sep/2016:00:04:23 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 197 "-" "Ruby"
::ffff:62.210.162.182 - - [23/Sep/2016:00:04:29 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"
::ffff:62.210.162.182 - - [23/Sep/2016:00:04:30 +0000] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 975 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1"
```

The bottom '/HNAP1/' fails with a 404, which is what I expect.
But these log lines all get 200:

```
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:10 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/?rnd=3342104796019809757566816 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:10 +0000] "GET http://50.117.47.67:43530/?rnd=2031422537804277052916912 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.111 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:49:11 +0000] "GET http://123.249.29.201:43210/?rnd=173003480482578803940608 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2;Windows NT 5.1;Windows NT 5.3; Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:31 +0000] "GET http://123.249.29.201:43210/?rands=_518421966013600083518500 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:31 +0000] "GET http://www.baidu.com/?rands=_14790662340951392923112 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:32 +0000] "GET http://50.117.47.15:28712/?rands=_71269649426275522095128 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
::ffff:61.157.96.112 - - [22/Sep/2016:23:56:33 +0000] "GET http://50.117.86.106/?rands=_146883056102225940108720 HTTP/1.0" 200 197 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)"
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('combined'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
// error handlers
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
   res.render('error', {
     message: err.message,
     error: err
   });
  });
}
// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
}); 
module.exports = app;
```

Here is my route/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'My Test Node App' });
});
module.exports = router;
```

And here is the bin/www script

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
/**
 * Module dependencies.
*/
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('newnode:server');
var http = require('http');
/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
console.log("PORT: ", port);
app.set('port', port);
/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */
var server = http.createServer(app);
/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */
server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */
function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);
  if (isNaN(port)) {
   // named pipe
   return val;
  }
  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }
  return false;
}
/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */
function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }
  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;
  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */
function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  console.log('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

This environment is after doing 'express newnode'.

I hope this explains well enough.

My question again is why do those 'http://www.baidu.com...' records end up getting a 200 instead of a 404?

Comment: We don't send answers via email here.  This site is for questions and answers HERE.  If you don't want to come back to the site to look for answers, then you will need to find a different site to use.

Comment: Why can't Stackoverflow send an email when the question has been answered? Many other sites do that.

Comment: @user1807480 It can; go to [your user preferences](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/1807480) and check "Email me my unread inbox messages."

Comment: I have that set but have not ever received any notifications. That is why I left my email address. I have checked this again and it is still set so I don't know why I don't get notified.

Comment: I would really like someone to answer this question. I have rephrased it and I think it is clear. I am using node.js and express.js and I have created the app.js and route files etc. The only routes that I think should work are '/', '/applitec', '/howitworks' and '/query' both as a get and a post. So I would think that someone asking to be routed to 'www.baude.com' would receive a 404 error message. Instead the route get a 200. I have tried routes like '/x' which get a 404 and even 'www.baude.com' which also get a 404, so why am I seeing the route answered with a 200?

Comment: @bartonlp You'll only get the email if you haven't seen the answer after 6 hours or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an "impossible URL." It's completely valid, although a full URL (e.g. http://example.org/foo) instead of just a path (`/foo`) is typically used for HTTP proxies where the full URL is the site the client wishes to visit via the proxy server.

**EDIT:** After reviewing the recently posted server-side routing code, there are no mistakes with the routing setup. Instead, it appears there is a bug in Express where [it only inspects the path portion of a request url](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/b69b7605b07b41273acc931d25ab585377bcd107/lib/router/index.js#L528) (ignoring any other parsed parts). I have filed an issue [here](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3088).

So in your particular case, those clients requesting a full URL (that have no paths) are currently receiving the response from your `/` route handler. Other full URLs (such as `http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif`) do not match because you have no `./public/cache/global/img/gs.gif` and no explicit route handler for `/cache/global/img/gs.gif`). For those you correctly see a 404 in the server-side logs.

**EDIT 2:** Surprisingly this is not considered a bug by the Express maintainers, so you will either have to check `req.originalUrl` and/or similar properties in each of your route handlers *or* include a generic middleware handler (before *any* other request handlers, except maybe logging middleware) that checks for these full URLs and handles them appropriately if you care about rejecting these kinds of full URL requests.

Here's an example middleware that you would add *first* to your middleware/route handler stack:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.originalUrl.charCodeAt(0) !== 47/*'/'*/)
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  next();
});
```

Comment: What I meant was, I think it is impossible given that my node server should only be answering for / . These requests are not for / and I would have thought that they should have received a 404 but instead they get a 200. How can that be happening?

Comment: It depends on your routes. Without seeing those, it's hard to say why.

Comment: I will try to simplify my app and if it still happens I will post the app.js and the index.js files.

Comment: I tried the app with a proxy server and the remote host address changes to the proxy address but the GET url is only the URL's that I accept. If I add a full url (http://something.com) I get a 404 error. That is what I expect.

Comment: I think I remember reading that but didn't think it meant what it said as any URL I was able to send via the browser gave me a 404 error if it was not a route. Thanks for the input, I will add a middleware that does as you said. I am not sure I don't consider that behavior a bug.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. How would I, from my browser, get the log as shown. When I do "bartonlp.org:<port>" any path after the port is the path that seems to be parsed. So anything except '/' is a 404. I can't get the "schema, host" part. The "schema, host" is 'bartonlp.org' and the schema is GET. As I said I am confused. If you could give me an example?

Comment: I've added an example middleware you might use.

Comment: Here is what I did: app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(req.hostname != 'www.bartonlp.org') {
    console.log("headers.host: ", req.headers.host);
    console.log("Hostname: ", req.hostname);
    console.log("Org Url: ", req.originalUrl);
    console.log("ERROR: Return");
    next(new Error('Bad Route'));
  }
  next();
}); It seems to work. But I would still like an example that would yield the message I was getting.

Comment: It seems that where I 'listen' makes a big difference. When I listen on port 8080 I get many hits where the 'req.hostname' is not my domain. But if I listen on port 3000 I get only hits to my domain. I did both for 24 hours. Is that just because 8080 is often used as a http port?

Comment: Most likely. Even though 8080 has been used for multiple purposes, it is often used by some web proxies, so that could explain that kind of traffic.